# how to get all friends in facebook using graph api v2.0 (ios)?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get user's list of friends by authanticate user and successfully when I use this code:

```
self.loginView.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"user_fridends", @"email"];

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/taggable_friends"
                             parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(
                                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error
                                          ) {
                          /* handle the result */
                          NSLog(@"%@", result);
                      }];
```

But I cannot get list of friends when I trying to get list of friends by another account

Comment: From API v2 on, you can only get friends that are users of the app as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/taggable_friends

> Use of this edge must be reviewed by Facebook before it can be called on behalf of people who use your app.

Without approval, it will only work for users with a role in the App (Admin/Dev/Tester). The proper way to get the friends is `/me/friends`, and it will only return those who authorized your App too.

Also, it is "user_friends", not "user_fridends".